# Is there a FSRef in iPhone SDK or is there something that can be FSRef's alternative?

Tags: iphone, audioqueueservices

The question may sound stupid, but the thing is this: I am learning how to use a Audio Queue, and the example I've taken (aqtest) has been a nice guide for me until I recently found out that aqtest is not for iPhone. (stupid me) I served around the Internet and found out that there is no FSRef for iPhone.

If possible, I want to find a way to work around FSRef thinggie. So here comes the question: can I use something else instead of FSRef that exists on the iPhone SDK? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

FSRefs are not available on the phone at all. FSRefs are a way of reprsenting a file reference, for most purposes the preferred replacement for the is an NSURL with a file: scheme.

Having said that, there definitely is a [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/index.html) example for the iPhone, it does not use FSRefs.

As for aqtest, I assume the code you are having issues with is:

```
FSRef fsref;    
XThrowIfError(FSPathMakeRef(filePath, &fsref, NULL), "Input file not found");

XThrowIfError(AudioFileOpen(&fsref, fsRdPerm, 0, &myInfo.mAudioFile), "AudioFileOpen failed");
```

Like I said, FSRef is no longer the preferred way to handle file refs, and is not available on the phone, NSURL is. So change over to the URL based version:

```
NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithCString: filePath];
if (!pathString) { printf("can't parse file path\n"); return; }

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];
if (! url) { printf("can't make file url\n"); return; }

XThrowIfError(AudioFileOpenURL (url, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0/*inFileTypeHint*/, &myInfo.mAudioFil), "can't open file");
```

That should work on the phone, of course a lot of aqtest itself won't work on the phone, running commandline tools on the device is not supported after all.

Comment: Actually I was running away from SpeakHere example because it confuses me. aqtest makes me understand a lot of things clearer when I read through it with the apple document about audio queue. For SpeakHere though, I'm not sure what goes where. I don't even know where to start looking in order to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the code in aqplay.cpp? It's in some sample code I grabbed from
Core Audio -> SimpleSDK -> AudioQueueTools.

It uses a `CFURLRef` to open its `AudioFileID`.

Most of that code looks like it should compile for the iPhone.